# Derivative of an Integral using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$ \frac d{dx} \int_\sqrt x^{x^2} \tan (6t) dt $$

I know I have to use the Fundamental theorem of calculus, however the $\sqrt x$ on the bottom of the Integral is mixing me up.

Comment: Look up the "Leibniz integral rule" and see if that helps.

Comment: Define $F(u):=\int_0^u\tan(6t)\,dt$.  You are asked to differentiate $F(x^2)-F(\sqrt{x})$, and this can be accomplished by combining the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\mapsto F(x)$ is a primitive of $x\mapsto \tan(6x)$.($F'(x)=\tan(6x)$). Then the integrand must be written as follows 
$$F(x^2)-F(\sqrt{x}).$$ Therefore, the derivative is 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(\sqrt{x}))= 2xF'(x^2)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}F'(\sqrt{x})= 2x \tan(6x^2)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\tan(6\sqrt{x}).$$

Comment: Shouldn't $F'(x)=\tan (6x)$ if $F$ is to be a primitive?

Comment: Yes. Edit has been done. Thank you.